# Не отображаются картинки в Django

Tags: python, django, url

Изучая Django, столкнулся с проблемой.
Попробовал создать медиа портал, как в данном [Уроке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32_MnD5YVn0&list=PLp_WN118C-Vfb9QER0cOHLoDWg2_2IqPb),
но уже несколько дней не могу справиться с тем, что не отображаются картинки (они хранятся в папке media).
[image: структура проекта]

> Класс Article в models

```
class Article(models.Model):

category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
slug = models.SlugField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_filename)
content = models.TextField()
likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
dislikes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return "Статья '{0}'' изкатегории '{1}'".format(self.title, self.category.name)
```

> создание url

```
def generate_filename(instance, filename):
    filename = instance.slug + '.jpg'
    return "{0}/{1}".format(instance, filename)
```

> Темплейт

[image: темплейт]

Перерыл уже кучу статей, но так решения и не нашел.
Подскажите, возможно, я в коде указываю что-то не так.

Comment: Не `scr`, а `src`

Comment: когда, что-то не отображается, первым делом проверяйте получаемый html отдельно в браузере - сможете избежать ошибок типа "Ааааа..."

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все оказалось так просто)